# Magic smoke from "AC 50-500V LED Digital Voltmeter Ammeter" when connected line-to-line on output of VFD

Tags: vfd

I wired 3  ["AC 50-500V 0-100A Persegi LED Digital Voltmeter Ammeter 110V 220V Tegangan Saat Ini Meter Voltammeter Mobil Volt Amp Tester Detektor"](https://id.aliexpress.com/item/33035907922.html) like this (but I paid a lot more for them...) Line-to-line on each phase of a 3 phase [VFD](https://www.tokopedia.com/listrikbatam/inverter-shzk-4kw-380v-3phase-3p-5hp-vfd-variable-frequency-drive?ref=wishlist) output. i.e. one RS, one RT, one ST of the RST phases.  I didn't really care about the voltage reading but need to keep an eye on the amps as I ramp up the motor via the VFD. They smoked and now the VFD is giving be a lost phase error — I guess it is fried too.

Just want to understand what happened.  The meters say they'll do up to 500V, so the 380 line to line is not too high.

Is it the frequency ramping up from the VFD or do they need a neutral? Are they just crap and should have worked but are junk?

Most likely I just don't understand something about the pixies coming out of a VFD, please help me learn.

[image: for science]
[image: also for science]

Comment: "I didn't really care about the voltage reading but need to keep an eye on the amps as i ramp up the motor via the VFD. " So how exactly did you have the meter connected? Were you trying to measure current or voltage?

Comment: 380V rms means 532V peak. Be (more) careful.

Comment: It would be interesting and educational to see the insides of this meter, to take note of what sort of voltage divider and power supply are being used. There really should be properly rated fuse for the voltage, and with such a small package there probably isn't room for the proper components and PC board spacing. And I'm surprised that it apparently damaged the VFD.

Comment: I wonder if maybe they used a capacitor voltage dropper for the power supply. The raw PWM from the VFD would cause a lot of current draw!

Comment: I’m with pstechpaul, we gotta see the insides for science.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the power supply is designed and built with a capacitor voltage dropper, which might work OK for a smooth sine wave, but a raw PWM will have high voltage transitions and high frequency components which exert high current into the other components, and results in the failure as shown in the picture.

I once designed a voltage relay with a similar circuit, and a customer reported that it had failed when using the equipment on a generator. I surmised that it might be random noise from brushes, but it was probably an inverter type generator which used PWM. I was not familiar with them at the time, and now I have a good explanation for the failure.

Comment: Any Idea what killed the VFD?

Comment: A well designed and properly constructed VFD should be able to withstand a short circuit, and in this case the current should have been limited by the wiring and the components in the meter. You may be able to do some troubleshooting of the VFD to determine just what may have failed. The usual failure mode is one or more IGBTs shorted, which can be determined by a DMM resistance test from outputs to the DC bus link or GND. Can you find a detailed manual and specs for the VFD?

Comment: The error code has 4 possibilities, 2 about having one phase lost due to wiring or winding in the motor.  I have ruled that out, the other 2 are " the driver board is faulty" and  "IGBT is faulty" so I guess one or more of the the IGBT's likely died. I had it apart, the boards look ok, nothing looks burnt.  Are the IGBTs the components connected to the large heat sink?   Can you share a link on how to test  IGBT?

Comment: Most modern VFDs use modules which include IGBTs along with drivers and other devices, and perhaps also the three phase input diodes. Check for shorts from each motor drive phase to the bus link and GND. You should also be able to check for the forward voltage of the IGBT body diodes. You should be able to find a video or online article with more explicit instructions.